# How to sketch Bezier Curves

Tags: numerical-methods, bezier-curve

I am reviewing for a numerical analysis exam, and I came across a question on drawing Bezier curves. 
"Draw on 3 separate figures planar Bezier curves
$$ c(t)=\sum_{k=0}^3p_k B_{3,k}(t)\hspace{5mm} t\in[0,1]$$
where $B_{3,k}(t)=\binom{3}{k} t^k(1-t)^{3-k}$ with control points on $p_k$ at the vertices of a unit square:

(a) $p_0=(0,0),p_1=(0,1),p_2=(1,1),p_3=(1,0)$

(b)$p_0=(0,0),p_1=(1,1),p_2=(0,1),p_3=(1,0)$

(c) $p_0=(0,0),p_1=(0,1),p_2=(1,1),p_3=(1,0)$"

I don't know how the control points interact with the equation $c(t)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I imagine you're supposed to work out the parametric equation using the given points.

Comment: Ok, but that is what I'm not sure about. How do I find the parametric equations?

Comment: Plug in the values of $p_0$, $p_1$, etc. and work out the binomial coefficients and the sums. For instance, in part (a) you have $c(t)=p_0B_{3,0}(t)+p_1B_{3,1}(t)+p_2B_{3,2}(t)+p_3B_{3,3}(t)$. Now work out each term. For instance, $p_1B_{3,1}(t)=(1,1)\binom{3}{2}t^2(1-t) = (3t^2(1-t),3t^2(1-t))$.

Comment: I see, I should have realized this sooner. Than you.

Comment: Fix $t$. Compute or draw the convex combinations $q_0=(1-t)p_0+tp_1$, $q_1=...$, $q_2=...$. Then $r_0=(1-t)q_0+tq_1$, $r_1=(1-t)q_1+tq_2$. Finally, $c(t)=(1-t)r_0+tr_1$. It should be feasible to do this for $t=1/4,1/2,3/4$ and then have a good idea how to sketch a qualitatively correct curve.